# Sed replace a non regular pattern

Tags: linux, sed

I have a bid spreadsheet and I have to replace some values, matching a non regular pattern of ones (i.e. 1) separates by commas. in its minimal pattern it can be 1,1, but it can goes higher, up to 10 replication (i.e. 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1...). I want to shrink the series just to 1.

This is an example of the data frame:

```
chr5    141587227   141587466   240 *   exon    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   chr5:140966508-140967052    DIAPH1_23361    chr5    141505592   141505799   208 *   promoter_flanking_region    0   1   0   1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 c(PCDHGA1_17708,PCDHGA2_17627,PCDHGA3_17505,PCDHGB1_17702,PCDHGA4_17576,PCDHGB2_17511,PCDHGA5_17603,PCDHGB3_17600,PCDHGA6_17551,PCDHGA7_17606,PCDHGB4_17598,PCDHGA8_17560,PCDHGB5_17553,PCDHGA9_17757,PCDHGB6_17668,PCDHGA10_17824,PCDHGB7_17671,PCDHGA11_17515,PCDHGA12_17651,PCDHGC3_17713,PCDHGC4_17790,PCDHGC5_17760)   2   2.31    81651
chr5    141587468   141588358   891 *   promoter_flanking_region    0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   c(chr5:140966508-140967052,chr5:140967690-140967917)    DIAPH1_23361    chr5    140944575   140944811   237 *   intron  0   0   0   1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   c(PCDHA1_11483,PCDHA2_56916,PCDHA3_11465,PCDHA4_11655,PCDHA5_11663,PCDHA6_11423,PCDHA7_11585,PCDHA8_11671,PCDHA9_11458,PCDHA10_56912,PCDHA11_11590,PCDHA12_56962,PCDHA13_11369,PCDHAC1_11533)   3   3.1 643220
chr5    141587468   141588358   891 *   promoter_flanking_region    0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   c(chr5:140966508-140967052,chr5:140967690-140967917)    DIAPH1_23361    chr5    141380219   141380588   370 *   intron  0   0   0   1,1,1,1,1,1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   c(PCDHGA1_17708,PCDHGA2_17627,PCDHGA3_17505,PCDHGB1_17702,PCDHGA4_17576,PCDHGB2_17511,PCDHGA5_17603,PCDHGB3_17600,PCDHGA6_17551)    3   3.41    207509
chr5    141587468   141588358   891 *   promoter_flanking_region    0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   c(chr5:140966508-140967052,chr5:140967690-140967917)    DIAPH1_23361    chr5    141381619   141381892   274 *   intron  0   0   0   1,1,1,1,1,1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   c(PCDHGA1_17708,PCDHGA2_17627,PCDHGA3_17505,PCDHGB1_17702,PCDHGA4_17576,PCDHGB2_17511,PCDHGA5_17603,PCDHGB3_17600,PCDHGA6_17551)    3   3.41    206157
```

`sed` attempt:

```
sed -i -r 's/\b1,\w+/1/g' file.txt
sed -i -r 's/\b\1.*/1/g' file.txt
```

My ideal output would be something like:

```
chr5    141587227   141587466   240 *   exon    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   chr5:140966508-140967052    DIAPH1_23361    chr5    141505592   141505799   208 *   promoter_flanking_region    0   1   0   1   c(PCDHGA1_17708,PCDHGA2_17627,PCDHGA3_17505,PCDHGB1_17702,PCDHGA4_17576,PCDHGB2_17511,PCDHGA5_17603,PCDHGB3_17600,PCDHGA6_17551,PCDHGA7_17606,PCDHGB4_17598,PCDHGA8_17560,PCDHGB5_17553,PCDHGA9_17757,PCDHGB6_17668,PCDHGA10_17824,PCDHGB7_17671,PCDHGA11_17515,PCDHGA12_17651,PCDHGC3_17713,PCDHGC4_17790,PCDHGC5_17760)   2   2.31    81651
chr5    141587468   141588358   891 *   promoter_flanking_region    0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   c(chr5:140966508-140967052,chr5:140967690-140967917)    DIAPH1_23361    chr5    140944575   140944811   237 *   intron  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   c(PCDHA1_11483,PCDHA2_56916,PCDHA3_11465,PCDHA4_11655,PCDHA5_11663,PCDHA6_11423,PCDHA7_11585,PCDHA8_11671,PCDHA9_11458,PCDHA10_56912,PCDHA11_11590,PCDHA12_56962,PCDHA13_11369,PCDHAC1_11533)   3   3.1 643220
chr5    141587468   141588358   891 *   promoter_flanking_region    0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   c(chr5:140966508-140967052,chr5:140967690-140967917)    DIAPH1_23361    chr5    141380219   141380588   370 *   intron  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   c(PCDHGA1_17708,PCDHGA2_17627,PCDHGA3_17505,PCDHGB1_17702,PCDHGA4_17576,PCDHGB2_17511,PCDHGA5_17603,PCDHGB3_17600,PCDHGA6_17551)    3   3.41    207509
chr5    141587468   141588358   891 *   promoter_flanking_region    0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   c(chr5:140966508-140967052,chr5:140967690-140967917)    DIAPH1_23361    chr5    141381619   141381892   274 *   intron  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   c(PCDHGA1_17708,PCDHGA2_17627,PCDHGA3_17505,PCDHGB1_17702,PCDHGA4_17576,PCDHGB2_17511,PCDHGA5_17603,PCDHGB3_17600,PCDHGA6_17551)    3   3.41    206157
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like

```
sed -r 's/\b1(,1)+\b/1/g'
```

I.e. match `1` followed by one or more occurrences of `,1`.

Comment: This cut everything is after 1(,1)+\b, even other columns

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want `awk '$28=1' input-file`

But maybe you want to filter a little bit and do

```
awk '$28 ~ "^1(,1)*$" {$28=1} 1' input-file
```

The first simply replaces the 28th column with `1`, while the 2nd only replaces the 28th column with `1` if it matches the regex `^1(,1)*$`